# Accessing DOM elements inside a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, element

I have a TR element that I have extracted into a variable in JavaScript. Now I want to further dig this element extract some specific content from there. For an example say there is a INPUT of TYPE=TEXT inside a TD. What I want is something like below.

```
var trElem = $("#idOfTrElem").get();//This gives me an array of the content of TR element.
```

Now I want to further dig the above variable and extract some values out of that. What shall I do?

Comment: You're asking how to get a item out of an Array? Or how to get a child of the `TR` element? I just can't tell what you're asking. Seems like you just need to read beginner's jQuery material.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason why you're calling `.get()` early? jQuery makes extracting the data pretty straightforward. For example, you could find all of the inputs in that row and log their values like this:

```
$('#idOfTrElem input[type=text]').each(function() {
  console.log(this.value);
});
```

I wrote a post about doing exactly what you're describing, which should be helpful: http://encosia.com/use-jquery-to-extract-data-from-html-lists-and-tables/

Comment: Problem is, to maintain the structure, I have put several other elements like TR->TD->SPAN->INPUT=TEXT. Seems like the way I have done is complicated.

Comment: @user3126973 The selector like `#id input` doesn't require that you specify the exact hierarchy. They can be in TDs or SPANs inside the TR, and this will still find them all. If you want to narrow to text inputs, you can change it to `#idOfTrElem input[type=text]`.

Comment: Got it! I'll keep that in mind. Your link is damn helpful... Thanks Dave! Hats off!

Answer (score -1):

```
var $tr = $("#idOfTrElem");
var trElem = $tr.get(0);
var $td = $tr.find("td:eq(0)")
var $input = $tr.find('input');
```

Is this helpful